# Using Plotly Express to plot data points on corresponding lines

Tags: python, plot, plotly

Good day!
So I am working with this dictionary data set in python. Say the dictionary looks like this:

```
time_sheet = {"hours_dan":[10, 8, 8, 11], "hours_john":[9, 8, 11], "hours_alex":[10, 8]}
```

My goal is to generate a scatter plot and have their names on the y-axis, and their hours on the x-axis. It would give me three lines and their time points on each line corresponding to their hours.

Is this achievable in Plotly Express? If not, what should I use to plot?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To create a graph, the data format must be converted. Convert from dictionary format to data frame format. Prepare an empty data frame and use a loop process to retrieve keys and values and merge them sequentially into a data frame. For graphs, symbol markers are added in addition to the basic form, and text positions are modified.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
time_sheet = {"hours_dan":[10, 8, 8, 11], "hours_john":[9, 8, 11], "hours_alex":[10, 8]}
for k,v in time_sheet.items():
    #print(k,v)
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'name':k[6:], 'hours':v})],axis=0)

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(df, x='hours', y='name', color='name', text='hours', symbol='name')
fig.update_traces(textposition="bottom right")
fig.show()
```

[image]